# VBA Macro Excel for grouping, finding and deleting duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I have no idea how to do this so I'm asking it here.
So this is the CSV I have in excel:

[image]

As you can see, we have dusplicates in the CSV in both price and special price.
Prices are bound to size. You can see that the size are the "same" yet they have spaces in them.

**What do I need?**

The VBA needs to group every sku, example:

[image]

After this, it needs to find duplicate prices and select those rows and delete the duplicates and NOT the default one, example:

[image]

Next SKU group:

[image]

Atleast, I think this is the procedure of doing this, if there's an other way, I'd like to hear it.

For me, I have no idea how I should do this. Maybe an Excel function?
Is this even possible?

**UPDATE 1**

So I've tried R3uK's solution and Marco Getrost's solution, R3uK's did best for me.

I've changed his VBA to the liking of my big CSV.
Here it is:

```
Sub test_Sj03rs()
With ActiveSheet
    'In column D
    With .Range("Y:Y")
        'Change all double spaces to single ones (being extra careful)
        .Replace What:="  ", _
                Replacement:=" ", _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
        'Change all slashes+spaces to single slash
        .Replace What:="/ ", _
                Replacement:="/", _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
        'Change all spaces+slashes to single slash
        .Replace What:=" /", _
                Replacement:="/", _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
    With .Range("A:AA")
        'To get rid of formulas if there is
        .Value = .Value
        'Remove duplicates considering all columns
        .RemoveDuplicates _
            Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27), _
            Header:=xlYes
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

And this is the file where it should be used for. Keep in mind that this file is roughly 13.000 rows.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

This is the CSV, for people who want to test.

[CSV](http://pastebin.com/E9v41kcj)

Comment: Not clear if you got this solved... If not do you mind sharing your csv file so we can work with real data and save a lot of typing...

Comment: @EEM, I'm updating my question with a pastebin with the csv

Comment: The link is not working, can't get to the page..

Comment: @EEM I'm going to try another link, it's working here though.

Comment: Sure the problem is that [http://pastebin.com] page is blocked here and cannot access it..

Comment: Not a good idea to change your original code in the question to the one revised from answers received as it distorts the essence of the question. Also when others come to your question cannot identify what the changes are.. Suggest that if you still want to post the revised code then do it keeping the original...

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you actually use the setup as described in your example. Otherwise you would want to make some changes to the code.

```
Sub test()

Dim rN&

With ActiveSheet

    .Columns("D").Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    rN = 1

    Do While .Cells(rN, 1).Value <> ""

        Do While (.Cells(rN, 1).Value = .Cells(rN + 1, 1).Value And .Cells(rN, 4).Value = .Cells(rN + 1, 4).Value _
        And .Cells(rN, 2).Value = .Cells(rN + 1, 2).Value And .Cells(rN, 3).Value = .Cells(rN + 1, 3).Value)

            .Cells(rN + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete

        Loop

        rN = rN + 1

    Loop

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
Sub test_Sj03rs()
Dim r as Range
With ActiveSheet
    'In column U (QTY)
    For Each r in .Range("Y:Y").Cells
        r.Value = r.Value * 1
    Next r
    'In column Y
    With .Range("Y:Y")
        'Change all double spaces to single ones (being extra careful)
        .Replace What:="  ", _
                Replacement:=" ", _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
        'Change all slashes+spaces to single slash
        .Replace What:="/ ", _
                Replacement:="/", _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
        'Change all spaces+slashes to single slash
        .Replace What:=" /", _
                Replacement:="/", _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
    With .Range("A:AA")
        'To get rid of formulas if there is
        .Value = .Value
        'Remove duplicates considering all columns
        .RemoveDuplicates _
            Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27), _
            Header:=xlYes
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So, I've tried this, but it didn't remove the rows with the duplicates. I'm updating my question with what I've changed to your solution to make it work for the bug CSV.

Comment: Ok, so you tried your adaption on the big CSV, and it didn't delete duplicates? Are you sure that some columns in the middle won't change between possible duplicate rows?

Comment: the only thing that changes are the slashes in column Y and QTY's changes from 9.0000 to 9 and 10.0000 to 10.

Comment: Ok, I added a correction for QTY column, try this one! And does the `replace`s seems to work? I.E. did the slash with spaces disappeared in column Y?

Answer (score 0):

Horrible I know, but if you don't have that much data this should work.

```
Sub remove()

Dim lRowNo As Long Dim lCheckRow As Long Dim sString As String Dim sCheckString As String

    For lRowNo = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        sString = Replace(Cells(lRowNo, 4), " ", "")

        For lCheckRow = 2 To lRowNo - 1

            sCheckString = Replace(Cells(lCheckRow, 4), " ", "")

            If sString = sCheckString Then

                Rows(lRowNo).EntireRow.Delete
                    lRowNo = lRowNo -1
                    exit for

            End If

        Next lCheckRow

    Next lRowNo

End Sub
```